# What is a Fermi surface?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I posted this question on the physics site, but then received immediately the sense that I won't be able to understand answers even if they come. So I hope it's all right if I post it here, since there appears to be mathematical interest as evidenced by this question:

[Topology and the 2016 Nobel Prize in Physics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251470/topology-and-the-2016-nobel-prize-in-physics/251588#251588)

---

Allow me to explain my confusion. Given a solid, I believe I have some feeling for the Fermi level. I can understand it, for example, as the characteristic parameter $\mu$ in the Fermi-Dirac distribution of energy levels for the electrons in the system:
$$f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)/kT}+1}$$
ignoring for the moment other physical interpretations. Thus, it is the unique energy level that has probability 1/2 of being occupied.

The definition of the Fermi surface, on the other hand, is usually given as 'the iso-surface of states with energy equal to the Fermi level' in the three-dimensional space of wave-vectors $k$, for example in this Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure

In other words, it is defined to be those $k$ such that
$$E(k)=\mu.$$
So far, so good. The problem is, I don't quite understand what $E(k)$ is.

One situation seems to be straightforward, namely a Fermi gas of identical particles. Then
$$E(k)=\frac{k^2}{2m}$$
and the Fermi surface is a sphere. However, if we are in an infinite periodic potential, the usual idealised model for Bloch theory, then the solutions to the Schroedinger equation come out in the form
$$\psi_{kn}(r)=e^{ik\cdot r}u_{kn}(r),$$
where $u_{kn}$ is a periodic function and $n$ is a discrete index for energy levels. In other words, for each wave vector $k$,

*there are many energy levels* $E_n(k)$.

So the equation for the Fermi surface would actually look like
$$E_n(k)=\mu.$$My question, therefore, is  which energy level is the $E(k)$ that occurs in the definition of the Fermi surface? Perhaps there is one Fermi surface for every level $n$? (Assuming that the levels vary continuously over the momentum space, enabling us to consistently index the levels for varying $k$.)

If I could elaborate on my confusion a little bit more, I don't quite understand the definition in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5742/2451) to this question:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5739/

It is stated that

> 'The Fermi surface is simply the surface in momentum space where, in the limit of zero interactions, all fermion states with (crystal) momentum $|k|<|k_F|$ are occupied, and all higher momentum states are empty. '

For one thing, as mentioned above, for any momentum $k$, there is an infinite sequence of fermion states. The other problem is that I'm not sure that the statement above defines a unique surface, even if I were able to somehow pick out a fermion state $\psi(k)$ for each $k$ that the statement refers to. (I would need to draw a picture to explain this point, which I don't have the competence to do.)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting p. 142 of the trusty [Ashcroft-Mermin](https://books.google.com/books?id=FRZRAAAAMAAJ) (who write $\mathcal E_F$ for your $\mu$):

> For each partially filled band there will be a surface in $k$-space separating the occupied from the unoccupied levels. The set of all such surfaces is known as the *Fermi surface*, and is the generalization to Bloch electrons of the free electron Fermi sphere. The parts of the Fermi surface arising from individual partially filled bands are known as the *branches* of the Fermi surface. We shall see (Chapter 12) that a solid has metallic properties provided that a Fermi surface exists.
>
> Analytically, the branch of the Fermi surface in the $n$th band is that surface in $k$-space (if there is one) determined by $$\mathcal E_n(\mathbf k)=\mathcal E_F.$$

As to "what $\mathcal E_n(\mathbf k)$ is": it arises from looking for eigenfunctions of a "single-electron" hamiltonian
$$
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+U(\mathbf r)\right)\psi(\mathbf r)=E\psi(\mathbf r)
$$
in the "Bloch" form: $\psi(\mathbf r)=e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}u(\mathbf r)$ with (Bravais lattice) periodic boundary conditions on $u$, i.e.
$$
\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac1i\nabla + \mathbf k\right)^2+U(\mathbf r)\right)u_{\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)=\mathcal E(\mathbf k)u_{\mathbf k}(\mathbf r).
$$

> Because of the periodic boundary condition we can regard [this] as a Hermitian eigenvalue problem restricted to a single primitive cell of the crystal. Because the eigenvalue problem is set in a fixed finite volume, we expect on general grounds to find an infinite family of solutions with *discretely* spaced eigenvalues, which we label with the band index $n$.

Comment: Many thanks. This is very helpful. However, I'm still confused by one thing. For the equation you write to define a surface in $k$-space, $ E_n(k)$ would have to be a *function of $k $*. However, if $n$ is an index for the band, each band is made up of many energy levels. So which level goes into the equation?

Comment: @MinhyongKim I believe this is answered by the edit I was making while you asked. There is a different eigenvalue problem for each $\mathbf k$, and $\mathcal E_n(\mathbf k)$ is its $n$-th eigenvalue.

Comment: Ah, I see. So there is a surface for each energy level, not just for each band?

Comment: @MinhyongKim Yes, I think that's it. (Several surfaces, or as they put it, one surface with several "branches". Of course, not all $n$ will enter for a given $\mathcal E_F$.)

Comment: Or perhaps it's that each band is actually quite thin, so that the equation defines 'essentially a surface'?

Comment: I've finally looked into Ashcroft and Mermin and deciphered that 'band' there just refers to an energy level.