# What is the status of the cobordism hypothesis?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, topological-quantum-field-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a symmetric monoidal (weak) $n$-category. A *framed extended TQFT of dimension $n$ with values in $\mathscr{C}$* is a symmetric monoidal functor from the *framed* bordism $n$-category $\textsf{Cob}^{\textsf{fr}}_n(n)$ into $\mathscr{C}$ (cf. **Lurie** 2008).

Let $Z : \textsf{Cob}^{\textsf{fr}}_n(n) \rightarrow \mathscr{C}$ be a framed extended $\mathscr{C}$-valued TQFT. A statement of the cobordism hypothesis (**Baez and Dolan** 1995; **Lurie** 2008) is that the evaluation functor

$$Z \mapsto Z(*)$$

determines a bijection between (isomorphism classes of) framed extended $\mathscr{C}$-valued topological field theories and (isomorphism classes of) *fully dualizable* objects of $\mathscr{C}$, so that for every object $C$ of $\mathscr{C}$ there is an essentially unique symmetric monoidal functor $Z_C : \textsf{Cob}^{\textsf{fr}}_n(n) \rightarrow \mathscr{C}$ such that $Z_C(*) \equiv C$.

Lurie has outlined a proof of the cobordism hypothesis:

- Jacob Lurie, On the Classification of Topological Field Theories. Current developments in mathematics 2008.1 (2008): 129-280. [doi:10.4310/CDM.2008.v2008.n1.a3](https://doi.org/10.4310/CDM.2008.v2008.n1.a3)

Grady and Pavlov have claimed a complete proof of a 'geometric' generalization of it:

- Daniel Grady and Dmitri Pavlov, The geometric cobordism hypothesis. arXiv preprint [arXiv:2111.01095](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01095). 2021.

The first statement of the cobordism hypothesis by Baez and Dolan is in:

- John C. Baez and James Dolan. Higher‐dimensional algebra and topological quantum field theory. Journal of mathematical physics 36.11 (1995): 6073-6105. [doi:10.1063/1.531236](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.531236)

On the physical implications of the cobordism hypothesis, [see this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309093/).

---

My question is: What is the status of the cobordism hypothesis, and in particular of Grady and Pavlov's claimed proof?

Comment: Concerning my two papers with Dan Grady, they are currently being revised in response to referee reports.  For the first paper a revised new version will be uploaded to arXiv in a few days or weeks, and the second paper will then follow.